# Can't boot Ubuntu (dual boot system) after migration on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, ssd

I'm facing out a strange problem with my laptop about Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual boot system with Windows 7.
After migration from HDD to SSD, the dual booting stopped to work (Windows start automatically)  and the Ubuntu partition has disappeared. There is no more uninstallation entry of Ubuntu in Programs and Features and the diskmgmt.msc doesn't seem to read the partition even if an Ubuntu folder is still present in Windows.
Before making mistakes I would like to know if is it possible to restore the dual boot or which step should I make to safely erase the Ubuntu files from Windows.
Below it's a screenshot of the diskmgmt command:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47682693/diskmgmt.jpg

Sorry for my English, I hope to have been clear about this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it and let you know if it works. But if in the future i would like to uninstall that Ubuntu partition from Windows 7, how should I do without uninstallation entry?

Answer (score 0):

The reason Windows cannot see your Linux partition is because Windows has limitations in what partitions it can see.  It cannot read that your partition is there, so it thinks it is blank space.  The reason you booted to Windows automatically is because Windows over-rid your grub boot loader.  You can fix this by booting into your Ubuntu install disc/USB and then installing Boot repair.  Follow the instructions listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for installing and using Boot repair, and let me know if you have any concerns or mis communications here, I will be happy to explain further if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1- First download boot repair disk from here: [Boot Repair Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

2- Then burn it into a USB or a CD-DVD

3- Boot your computer from that device

4- Choose your language

5- Choose "Recommended Repair"

6- Reboot your computer.

It will fix your grub (I hope)...